# Parenthesis within arrays

Tags: tables, arrays

I use Typora. I have obtained the following, using an array and multiple quads :

[image]

```
$\begin{array}{lcl} P_4 & = & P_1 & \cup & \\ 
& \cup & P_2 & \cup & \\ 
& \cup & \left \{ S \xrightarrow[(1)]{} b \quad 
    \mid \quad S_1 \rightarrow b \in P_1, 
         \quad b \in X \cup \left \{ \lambda \right \} 
         \quad \right \} &\cup & \\ 
&\cup & \left \{ S \xrightarrow[(2)]{} bC \quad 
   \mid \quad S_1 \rightarrow bC \in P_1, 
        \quad b \in X, \quad b \ne \lambda, 
        \quad C \in V_1 \quad \right \} 
\end{array}$
```

instead, I would want to obtain the following:

[image]

I have tried, but, I obtain an error if I use parenthesis within array.
Please, can you tell me, how can I obtain that tabular positioning? Thanks! :)

Comment: I think you can adapt codes from answers to this post. They used a lot of alignments.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416555/14757

Comment: @Sigur in the cases listed, there aren't rows of parethesis within the same array.

Comment: No problem. Just read your formula as a system of formulas and align the symbols, including the bars and braces, and unions.

Comment: Please, can you explain it better or can you post a simple example?

Comment: Done. You can control the space between cols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a deliberately differently-styled answer, which uses a single `align*` environment and no `array` environments. Observe that the `\cup` symbols at the starts of rows 2, 3, and 4 are shifted to the right of the `=` symbol in row 1, to emphasize that `p` (at the start of row 1) is the union of the remaining stuff on all four lines. With such a layout, it's also not necessary to provide `\cup` symbols at the ends of rows 1, 2, and 3.

Observe also that I use `\Bigm|` instead of `\mid` in rows 3 and 4, to provide some more visual support for what the main things in those two rows are. I also use simple spaces instead of `\quad`, as I believe the latter inserts *too much* horizontal displacement.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P_4 &= P_1 \\
    &\quad \cup P_2 \\
    &\quad \cup\Bigl\{ S\xrightarrow[(1)]{} b\phantom{C} 
               \Bigm|  S_1\to b\phantom{C}\in P_1,\  
                       b\in X\cup\{\lambda\} 
               \Bigr\} \\
    &\quad \cup\Bigl\{ S\xrightarrow[(2)]{}bC 
               \Bigm|  S_1\to bC\in P_1,\ 
                       b\in X,\ 
                       b\notin\lambda,\ C\in V_1
               \Bigr\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would exploit having a short second term:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
P_4 = P_1
& \cup P_2 \\
& \cup \Bigl\{ S \xrightarrow[(1)]{} b\hphantom{C} \Bigm|
         S_1 \rightarrow b \in P_1, b \in X \cup \{\lambda\}
       \Bigr\} \\
& \cup \Bigl\{ S \xrightarrow[(2)]{} bC \Bigm|
         S_1 \rightarrow bC \in P_1,
          b \in X,  b \ne \lambda,
          C \in V_1
       \Bigr\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The trailing `\cup` symbols do nothing and appear as hanging from nowhere. I see no real reason for artificially aligning unconnected bits, except for the vertical bar. To the contrary, the asymmetry between the terms will help the reader in spotting the differences.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One way to accomplish this is using a `\hphantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{lcll} P_4 & = & P_1 & \cup  \\ 
& \cup & P_2 & \cup  \\ 
& \cup & \left \{ 
\makebox[0pt][l]{$S \xrightarrow[(1)]{} b \quad$}
\hphantom{S \xrightarrow[(2)]{} bC \quad}
 \mid \makebox[0pt][l]{$\quad S_1 \rightarrow b \in
P_1, \quad b \in X \cup \left \{ \lambda \right \} \quad$}
\hphantom{\quad S_1 \rightarrow bC \in P_1, \quad b \in X, \quad b \ne \lambda, \quad C \in V_1 \quad} \right \} &\cup  \\
&\cup& \left \{ S \xrightarrow[(2)]{} bC \quad \mid \quad S_1 \rightarrow bC \in P_1, \quad b \in X, \quad b \ne \lambda, \quad C \in V_1 \quad \right \} 
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative: `\vphantoms`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{lclclll} P_4 & = & P_1 & & & & \cup  \\ 
& \cup & P_2 & & & & \cup  \\ 
& \cup & \left \{ 
S \xrightarrow[(1)]{} b \right.&  \mid &  S_1 \rightarrow b \in
P_1, \quad b \in X \cup \left \{ \lambda \right \}& 
\left.\vphantom{S \xrightarrow[(1)]{} b}\right\} &\cup  \\
&\cup& \left\{ S \xrightarrow[(2)]{} bC \right.& \mid 
& S_1 \rightarrow bC \in P_1, \quad b \in X, \quad b \ne \lambda, \quad C \in V_1 
& \left.\vphantom{S \xrightarrow[(1)]{} b}\right\}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

But do you really like the outcome? (To me it looks almost as terrible as a pineapple on a pizza ;-)

Comment: thanks, but, also the contents of the parenthesis must be aligned as tabular.

Comment: Nothing can be terrible like  on , +1

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple to do that with `alignat`, and you have full control on the spacing between the element of the formula:

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makebox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{6}
  P_4 & \makebox*{${}\cup{}$}{$ = $} P_1\\
  &\cup P_2 & & & & & & & & & & \cup\\
 & \cup \Bigl\{S \xrightarrow[(1)]{} b & & \mid S \xrightarrow{} b\in P_1, & \enspace & b\in X\cup\{\lambda\} & \enspace & & & \Bigr\} &\enspace & \cup\\
 & \cup \Bigl\{S \xrightarrow[(2)]{} b C& & \mid S \xrightarrow{} b\in P_1, &\enspace & b\in X ,& \enspace & b\ne\lambda, & \enspace C\in V_1&\Bigr\} & &\cup
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Forgot this! I'll complete in a moment.

Answer (score 3):

Adapting [this answer by Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416560/14757), we can produce the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
\begin{array}{rcl c l c l c r c r c }
P_4 & = &    P_1  &&&&&&&&& \cup \\
    & \cup & P_2  &&&&&&&&& \cup \\
    & \cup & \Bigl\{ S \xrightarrow[(1)]{} b & \mid & S_1 \to b  \in P_1, && b \in X \cup  \{ \lambda \} &&                  && \Bigr\}            & \cup \\
    & \cup & \Bigl\{ S \xrightarrow[(2)]{} bC & \mid & S_1 \to bC \in P_1, && b \in X,                    &&   b\neq \lambda, && C\in V_1   \Bigr\} & \cup 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]